# How exactly could I prove that if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x$ & $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = y$, then x = y

Tags: limits

I'm given this:

Prove that if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x$ & $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = y$, then $x = y$

I mean, it seems so painfully obvious that if the same limit converges to two different variables, then those variables have got to be equal, right? But there's got to be more to it than that, right? Should I try examining the contrapositive to this where x $\ne$ y?

Comment: Consider writing $x-y = \lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n-x_n)$.

Answer (score 5):

Given $\epsilon>0$, find positive integer $N$ such that $|x_{n}-x|<\epsilon/2$ and $|x_{n}-y|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n\geq N$.

So $|x-y|\leq|x_{N}-x|+|x_{N}-y|<\epsilon$. This is true for all $\epsilon>0$, so $|x-y|=0$, so $x=y$.